# How to ignore adding duplicate phone number to mysql table in java

Tags: java, mysql

```
public void registration() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    System.out.println("Do you want to register to pay advance in online type yes or  no");
    boolean flag = false;
    Set <String> pNumber = new HashSet <String>();
    String input = scan.next();
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        String name = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter password");
        String pWord = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Re-enter password");
        String reEnter = scan.next();
        if (pWord.equals(reEnter)) {
            String confirm = reEnter;
            System.out.println("Your password created successfully");
            System.out.println("Enter your phone number");
            String phoneNumber = scan.next();
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            conn = MansionDBConnect.getConnection();
            String queryTwo = "select phone_number from registration";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryTwo);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                pNumber.add(rs.getString(1));
                //System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
            System.out.println(pNumber.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < pNumber.size(); i++) {
                if (pNumber.contains(phoneNumber)) {
                    System.out.println("Already number registered");
                    //pNumber.remove(phoneNumber);
                    System.out.println(pNumber);
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (pNumber.equals(phoneNumber)) {
                System.out.println("Already number registered");
            }
            String query = "insert into registration (username,password,phone_number)values(?,?,?)";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, name);
            ps.setString(2, confirm);
            ps.setString(3, phoneNumber);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Your record created successfully try login");
        } else {
            System.out.println("password mismatch found try again");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("For more details please call us");
    }
}
```

I am trying to ignore the user in `registration()` if a user with the same mobile number already exists. I am able to find if it exist but after that the rest of the code should be executed. But the `query` keeps executing. Which condition should be added?

Comment: If it breaks out of the loop the execution continues instead why not take the user back to re-enter the phone number

Comment: Thanks for your time...yeah i can tell them in sysout enter new number but after that the query should be executed right which condition i can use after checking phone number to execute insert query along with java code... Connel

Comment: If you want to handle it in the application, find out the exception being thrown since I'm sure you have give that column a unique constraint. When the exception fires give your own error message. Else while pNumber == phonenumber repeat from beginning don't break to end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `flag` that you used to tell if the record exist like this:

```
if(!flag) {
   //put here the insert statement
}
```

Comment: This suggestion has a problem, because in between the time the `flag` is computed and the insert call is made, someone else may have inserted a duplicate phone number.  The only way to avoid this would be to use a serializable transaction, but that would be overkill her IMO.

Comment: Hi Niver it is working just fine would you please tell me before that i have used if(boolean = false){my insert code} why it is not worked

Comment: @Ravi because you were finding whether the number exist but you were not using this fact to condition the insert statement.

Comment: no Niver what i am saying is you added if(!flag){  code }.....right....? it is working fine now
instead i have tried with if(boolean = flase) {  code }  ....what is the difference between these two Niver...?

Comment: Oh, I get you.. You should have `if(flag == false){} `

Answer (score 1):

The best approach here probably is to add a unique index on the `phone_number` column in your `registration` table:

```
ALTER TABLE registration ADD UNIQUE (phone_number);
```

With a unique index in place, inserts using a duplicate phone number should throw an exception, which you may catch and handle:

```
try {
    String query = "insert into registration (username, password, phone_number) values(?,?,?)";
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, name);
    ps.setString(2, confirm);
    ps.setString(3, phoneNumber);
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
    System.out.println("Already number registered");
}
```

Comment: Still this would return a constraint violation exception if duplicate phone number is inserted. It should still be handled application side. But I agree that this should be present as constraint on db level.

Comment: @NiVeR What is wrong with an exception?  There are a few ways to write queries to handle this problem, but I like an exception because it lets us explicitly handle a duplicate phone number.

Comment: Hi Tim, user should know they cannot register with same mobile number and your approch will suits and  if i make phone number as primary key also it wont accept duplicate right...so i have tried writing code until the user register with unique value in phonenumber tim

Comment: Nothing wrong, just said that you should mention that it should be handled application side.

Comment: yes Niver tim told good one to store only unique elements in mysql table this also nice way but i struggled in adding insert query in java

Comment: Hi TIm thanks i made changes accordingly it is working fine too thanks again for guiding me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would say you should  ensure you have added `UNIQUE` to your phone number field in your MySql database:

`ALTER TABLE registration
ADD UNIQUE (phone_number);`

Also replace this line:

`String queryTwo = "select phone_number from registration";`

to

`String queryTwo = "select phone_number from registration where phone_number = '" + phoneNumber + "'";`

perform a check if any row is returned.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Bro for your time, as a beginner thanks for assisting me to try with new stuffs.